# How to add lib files and headers to a C++ Project

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have been using libcurl in a C++ project.
I have added the libcurl Include and Library directory's to the VC++ Directories and added the .lib file to the Linkers Input Additional Dependencies.

Everything works fine but when I check in my code (TFS) and somebody gets it on another machine they cannot build etc due to not having libcurl installed on their machine or installed in different paths etc.

How do I add all the necessary files to my C++ Solution so that anyone getting the project from source control can build and link without error.

Thanks

The solution I went with was too add the library file to a folder within my solution, then add

```
$(SolutionDir)libs\curllib.lib
```

To the Additional Dependencies within Linker->Input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not add the library to the solution. you should distribute the library along the source code. Place it in a subdirectory of the project so that it goes along the whole project source. Then configure the path in Additional Library Dependencies. That way the people should be able to link appropriately when building from source.

Comment: If I do that, how can I make the .lib file path relative and not specific to my own machine?

Comment: You can use the Visual Studio path variables. For example `$(SolutionDir)` (double-check that) will give you the root directory of the solution. Then concatenate that with the rest of the path to the subdirectory, containing the library. Example: `$(SolutionDir)/libs/libcurl.lib`

Comment: Am I correct in assuming if I add the libcurl.lib via your method above to the Additional Library Dependencies within Linker General. I do not need to add anything to the Linker Input Additional Dependencies?

Comment: I am not sure about that. You should probably check and see. Please do tell afterwards.